How to set up a constraint on a column for a value to be greater than a number?
Normally, we could use a syntax such as age Integer CHECK (age > 0) but Snowflake gives an Error.
What is the alternate for the "CHECK" constraint on a column value in Snowflake if possible?
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE persons (person email VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,age INTEGER CHECK (age>0)


Are you concerned with upstream business rules not being applied correctly or limiting data from being included in end-user queries of the data?  There are lots of ways to enforce these things, but constraints aren't one of them.

Snowflake supports very limited types of constraint, and enforces even fewer: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview
There is no way, that I am aware of, of enforcing the type of constraint you are talking about in Snowflake
